# Not logged in error message while connecting to ftp server

Tags: java, ftp

I am using com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient to login my FTPSERVER

using the following command ftpClient.login(USER_NAME,PASSWORD());

am using com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.

But some times am getting "Not logged in" error.

FTP server has a domain name. but i log in only with user name and pwd and host name as the dns name.

In some 10, 15 , 20 minutes I get a "not logged in" error.

It is not occuring always, not in any specific pattern also, but immedietly after the error the connection is succesful.

[INFO] [FTPPull : getFTPConnection] - Error occured while FTP login : Not logged in The host is xxx.yyy.in The port used is 6370 [12] [2011-11-10 14:59:18 CET ]

but next connection was succesful

[INFO] [FTPPull : getFTPConnection] - Login Successful [12] [2011-11-10 15:09:18 CET ]

Please help, not sure why sometimes getting connected and sometimes not connected.

Regards,
Sridevi

Comment: Command channel connection timeout which means you have to reconnect?

Comment: Oh Okay, is that is because of timeout?, Can I set the connection timeout property in FTP server?

Comment: You definitely can, but it depends on the FTP server implementation of course. Also, is your TCP socket using keepalive?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, can I set the TCP Socket by default set alive, if yes , How will I set in my code when my first connection to the ftp server is made. I use a third party ftpclient to connect with the ftp server.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that there is a timeout at the FTP command channel level. When your client detects it, it reconnects automatically, as you have witnessed.

Now, you have to understand where that timeout comes from: either the client side or the server side:

- first check the configuration on the server side: can you change the command channel timeout to a higher value, or even to infinite?
- then check the API for your client (I personally use Apache Commons' FTP client): does it have a way to set the timeout too?
- finally, check in the API whether sockets to the command channel use TCP keepalive; if not, does it have a method to set it? If you pass a Socket yourself to the constructor, make it keepalive before constructing your client instance.

The most likely scenario is however that the FTP server itself closes the command channel. Changing that is implementation dependent.

A good way to check the server side disconnection is to use a command line FTP client to check. I personally use `lftp` for that:

```
$ lftp ftp://some.ftp.site/
lftp> debug
# idle, idle...
# if the server times out, it will tell you so
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That ftp server is our clinet side domain server. I will set the timeout property. Normally when the timeout is set to -1 then it will wait for infinite time right? I have a setter method for my timeout, but the spec did not specify about -1 value, anyway will do a test, thanks a lot.

Comment: •first check the configuration on the server side: can you change the command channel timeout to a higher value, or even to infinite?
Can you tell me how will I set it windows / linux?

Comment: No I cannot, since I don't know what FTP server you use -- and I only have real experience with vsftpd.